# Sort a typed Scala HashMap

Tags: scala

I searched the answers of sorting a scala HashMap. 
Which is

```
opthash.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
```

I just want to sorted by key, thus the above solution should apply.

However, here is my situation that the above solution resulted in an error:

```
def foo (opthash : HashMap[Int,String]) = {
    val int_strin_list = opthash.toSeq.sortBy(_._1);
    "return something"
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
value sortBy is not a member of Seq[(Int, String)]
```

Did I miss something? I am pretty sure that sortBy is a member of type Seq...

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm able to compile your method flawlessly on 2.10 <s>What version of scala do you use?</s> Looks like even 2.8 (that is 2003) have sortBy for Seq.

Comment: And [online demo that shows that this really works](http://www.scalakata.com/524b53dfebb25c7f5d828755) (click green button to run)

Comment: The compiler objects to the use of semicolons and underscores in variable names...

Comment: Thanks. I updated to 2.10 and solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use Scala HashMap and not java HashMap. Are you sure you did not misread the error message?

```
scala> import java.util.HashMap
import java.util.HashMap

scala> def foo (opthash : HashMap[Int,String]) = {
     |     val int_strin_list = opthash.toSeq.sortBy(_._1);
     |     "return something"
     | }
<console>:13: error: value toSeq is not a member of java.util.HashMap[Int,String]
           val int_strin_list = opthash.toSeq.sortBy(_._1);
                                        ^
```

The right way to go is:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

scala> def foo (opthash : HashMap[Int,String]) = {
     |     val int_strin_list = opthash.toSeq.sortBy(_._1);
     |     "return something"
     | }
foo: (opthash: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,String])String
```

Or too use the mutable HashMap if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks. I was using scala 2.7. After ensuring of using scala's HashMap and using the latest scala, the problem was solved!!